# How to get an event from button in jquery mobile dynamic page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a dynamic page using jquery mobile, how to get an event after creating this page? Also i need an alert from this button.

this is my code:

```
 $("#test").on('click',function(){
    var newPage = $("<div data-role=page data-url=testpage><div data-role=header>        <h1>TEST</h1></div><div data-role=content> <input type='button' value='clic kMe' id='click_me'> </div></div>");
    newPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );
    $.mobile.changePage( newPage );
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
    $(document).on('click','#click_me',function() {
        alert('Click');
    });
```

or in case of your code:

```
$("#test").on('click',function(){
    var newPage = $("<div data-role=page data-url=testpage><div data-role=header><h1>TEST</h1></div><div data-role=content> <input type='button' value='clic kMe' id='click_me'> </div></div>");
    $(document).on('click','#click_me',function() {
        alert('Click');
    }); 
    newPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );
    $.mobile.changePage( newPage );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, click event is firing now, i need an event after create this page,

Comment: This kind of binding will work always no matter if element exists in DOM or not. Do you maybe need anything else?

Comment: yea!, i want to append some data to this page, so how i get pageshow event form this page?

Comment: You will need to generate an id for that page,lets say that id is page1, then your code would work like this: $(document).on('pageshow ', '#page1', function(){ });  Because this is delegated binding you can do it after the click bind I showed you in my answer or in any other place. But remember page id is important, it is used so correct page event can be bound to a correct page.