# Jquery mobile Fill in Input Field by Clicking Link in a dynamic page

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic

I already know the solution for normal pages, [Fill in Input Field by Clicking Link with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653950/fill-in-input-field-by-clicking-link-with-jquery) but I need the same solution for a Jquery mobile dynamic page. 
The button solution, [How to get an event from button in jquery mobile dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732517/how-to-get-an-event-from-button-in-jquery-mobile-dynamic-page) works fine.
If I added the function at $(document).ready(function() and in the dynamic page like the button solution clicking the link will not do anything.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code and what you've tried? From what I understand of your question you're just looking for the right selector?

Answer (score 1):

Given this markup:

```
    <input id="TheTextBox" type="text" />
    <a href="#" class="special_field_link" data-role="button">The Special Text</a>
```

You could create your click event in the jQM "pagecreate" event of the page:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(){
    $(".special_field_link").on("click", function(){
        $("#TheTextBox").val($(this).html());
    });
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yBfFd/)**